# How to intercept Sendmessage API

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, window-messages

I need to intercept SendMessage API to prevent someone getting text from a particular window by sending WM_GETTEXT  . so please suggest me how to do this

Comment: Do you own the said window? It would probably be easier to come up with a sensical solution if you told us why you need to prevent that, too.

Comment: yeah ...actually we r working on file protection means we r taking care of data in the file so if someone try to copy the data by sending GET_TEXT message via SendMessage API we r not able to protect right now so we need protect data leak from SendMessage Method also ..

Comment: Run the application in a different user session.

Comment: would you please elaborate your answer ..

Comment: Why are you putting sensitive file data in a place where a WM_GETTEXT message can get to it in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to simply subclass the window procedure of the target `HWND` and discard any `WM_GETTEXT` messages that you do not invoke yourself.

Comment: Or simply return a null string for all `WM_GETTEXT` queries, and have your internal text management use a private mechanism. A lot of controls do this already. (For example, sending a `WM_GETTEXT` to a treeview control does not return anything interesting.)